# Change TextInputLayout stroke width and hint font

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I want to change the stroke width from the new TextInputLayout from Material Design to look like the uploaded picture, however when I use:

`app:boxStrokeWidth="0.5px"`

It doesn't work, I also use the debug mode and found this code on the TextInputLayout.class:

`this.boxStrokeWidthPx = this.boxStrokeWidthDefaultPx;`

Which gives me the sense that It automatically uses a 2px width by default.
How can I change this width, and also make the hint text bolder??

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Set the below in your resources folder, under `dimens.xml`

```
 <dimen name="mtrl_textinput_box_stroke_width_default">1dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="mtrl_textinput_box_stroke_width_focused">2dp</dimen>
```